# How to lower a figure?

Tags: formatting, figure-placement

[image]

Here is the code I have for the following image. The problem is that I need the right-most figure to be centered in the brackets but the bottom is always on the center. How would I lower/center it while keeping it in the bracket? Thank you!

```
\[ \left\langle \hopf \right\rangle = A\left\langle \hopfone \right\rangle+A\left\langle \includegraphics[height= .75 cm]{Note Jul 31, 2023.jpg} \right\rangle\]
```

Comment: `\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height= .75 cm]{Note Jul 31, 2023.jpg}}}`

Comment: @SandyG That works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: With `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` you can do `\includegraphics[valign=c,height= .75 cm]{Note Jul 31, 2023.jpg}`